# Why does Gamma distribution appear in other distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, gamma-distribution

Why does gamma distribution appear a lot? Gamma distribution appears in Chi-square distribution, Erlang distribution. It also appears in the expected value $(E[X])$ of Pareto distribution and Weibull distribution.

Basically, I wanted to know how does gamma distribution connects to all these distributions intuitively.

Comment: The $\chi^2$ and Erlang distributions are just special cases of the gamma distribution. The Weibull distribution is one example of a generalized gamma distribution. They are all related simple because they are generalizations/special cases of each other.